# Compare iOS with Android Development

Tags: android, ios

I am iOS Developer and I want to study Android coding, Does any document compare those two differences? Include APP/View life cycle, data structure (ex NSMutableArray <-> Array List), ios TableView as Android ListView...etc

Comment: It is probably not the best way learning how to develop for android. Better find some small samples and intros

Answer (score 1):

The official [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) should get you started.

They have all the samples and training to help you understand how Android Development works.

The first basic training [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) which will get you started with bit more than "Hello World".

You can find essential basic information about `Activity` (screen/page whatever it's called in iOS) lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle).

[image]

For in memory objects, we have the whole of [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) framework of Java that we can use in Android, which includes `ArrayList` as one of the options.

For permanent data storage we have options like [`SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/) which is a database management library, [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store key value pairs and plain-text or binary files anywhere in the system or in the protected application data directory itself which is sandboxed to restrict access by other applications.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, In ios development has foundation framework, The foundation framework defined most basic data structure (NSString NSArray NSDictionary ...etc), Has any information to know array in ios is nsarray ; in android is arraylist?

Comment: Yes we have to whole `Collections` framework in Java that we can use in Android which includes `ArrayList`. Updated the answer with details about it.